# Taylor expansion of fraction involving hyperbolic functions

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

How can I calculate the Taylor series of this function about $x=0$, $y=0$?
$$f(x,y)= \frac{1}{\coth x + \coth y}$$
I can't seem to work out the limits of the derivatives about the origin?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is not defined (or not continuous if you allow $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$-valued) on the line $x=-y$.

Comment: @user10354138 What about if I only allow x and y to take positive real numbers?

Comment: So $(0,0)$ isn't in the domain.